# text extraction from web pages

Tags: java, url, html-parsing

I'm working on a program that reads the content of this page: http://www.pogdesign.co.uk/cat/ and alerts me when one of my favourite tv series is scheduled and on which day of the month. In this program I also would like to have a `JFrame` that display all months (maybe a `JTabbedPane`) and in each month I want to list all episodes of my favourite tv series with the relative day of the month.

I have already wrote something using "[jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/)" in order to extract text from a html web page.
I need to understand what approach to use in order to do implements these steps:

1. find the day of a month when the episodes of a specific tv series
   are scheduled and save them somewhere.
2. get `a ref` links of those
   episodes and use them to find the broadcast time of each episode and
   save them somewhere.

So what do you think is a good strategy to do something like that? 
Is the Java HTML Parser enough to complete a program like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest you to get a list of  item that have the title you want to find, and after use the parent() method (JSOUP) to know the relative day all in one step.

I think you can easy do it with Jsoup.